# Foundation datepicker, end date (and time) cannot be before start date (and time)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datepicker, zurb-foundation

I am using the Foundation-Datepicker and I have it so the user can only pick a start date that is after current date (i.e. all other values are unable to be selected).

I would like the end date to work in the same manner where the user can only pick a date after the start date.

I have the dates (days) working, i.e. user cannot select 1 January 2016 as the end date if the start date is 3 January 2016.

My first problem is due to the fact that I cannot have the start date to be the same as the end date, and secondly because I am also using time I would like it to disable all selections following the start date/time for end date/time popup.

i.e. user can select 1 January 2016, 13:00 as start and 1 January, 14:00 as end.

My code is the following:

```
// Get Date of today
var newDate = new Date();
// Prase newDate
var now = new Date(newDate.getFullYear(), newDate.getMonth(), newDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
// Initialize datepicker with restricted date
var startDate = $('.has-datepicker').fdatepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy - hh:ii",
    pickTime: true,
    onRender: function (date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
    if (e.date.valueOf() > endDate.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(e.date);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        endDate.update(newDate);
    }
}).data('datepicker');

var endDate = $('.has-datepicker2').fdatepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy - hh:ii",
    pickTime: true,
    onRender: function (date) {
        return date.valueOf() <= startDate.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {

}).data('datepicker');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// implementation of disabled form fields
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var checkin = $('#dpd1').fdatepicker({
    onRender: function (date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.update(newDate);
    }
    checkin.hide();
    $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('#dpd2').fdatepicker({
    onRender: function (date) {
        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```

try like this.. better go through the site and docs fully

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I saw that example that you posted (http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/example.html#deps-example) However that only applies for dates and I would like it to be applied to dates and time.